# fadeIn combination with css opacity animation

Tags: jquery, css

Take a look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/65HsU/).
I've got a series of divs and some of them may have a css opacity animation.
If i click the fadeIn button, the effect look strange in the divs with the css opacity animation: they don't fadeIn, instead they start directly with a given opacity value.

Is it possible to make every divs fadeIn starting from opacity value set to zero?

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="asd red"></div>
  <div class="asd orange"></div>
  <div class="asd green"></div>
  <div class="asd blue"></div>
  <div class="asd magenta"></div>
  <div class="asd yellow"></div>
  <div class="asd red"></div>
  <div class="asd orange"></div>
  <div class="asd green"></div>
  <div class="asd blue"></div>
  <div class="asd magenta"></div>
  <div class="asd yellow"></div>
  <div class="asd red"></div>
  <div class="asd orange"></div>
  <div class="asd green"></div>
  <div class="asd blue"></div>
  <div class="asd magenta"></div>
  <div class="asd yellow"></div>
</div>
<div>
  <input type="button" id="fade" value="fade" />
</div>
```

Css code:

```
body {
  background:#404040;
}

.asd {
  float:left;
  display:block;
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}
.orange {
  background-color: orange;
}
.green {
  background-color: green;
  animation:opacityChange 2s infinite;
    -webkit-animation:opacityChange 2s infinite; /* Safari and Chrome */
}
.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}
.magenta {
  background-color: magenta;
}
.yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}

@keyframes opacityChange {
    0%      {opacity:1;}
    50%     {opacity:0.5;}
    100%    {opacity:1;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes opacityChange { /* Safari and Chrome */
    0%      {opacity:1;}
    50%     {opacity:0.5;}
    100%    {opacity:1;}
}
```

jQuery code:

```js
$("#fade").click(function() {
  $(".asd").hide();
  $(".asd").fadeIn(1000);
});
```

Comment: The result of your code has button covered by fiddle "RESULT" cover, which makes button unclickable though :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this

http://jsfiddle.net/4HvZk/2/

```
$("#fade").click(function() {
    $(".asd").hide().removeClass('ani').fadeIn(1000, function() {
        $('.green').addClass('ani');
    });
});
```

CSS

```
.green {
  background-color: green;
}
.ani {
  background-color: green;
  animation:opacityChange 2s infinite;
    -webkit-animation:opacityChange 2s infinite; /* Safari and Chrome */
}
```

Separate the animation css from the background colour so you can control it better